# What happens when you call receive_message() on an empty SQS queue?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

I'm trying to count the number of times a PHP process calls receive_message() on an empty AWS SQS queue. Right now I have it working by counting every time MessageID is not set the queue is empty. Is there a more direct way of checking?

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-queue-message-identifiers.html

```
if(!isset($sqsMessage->body->ReceiveMessageResult->Message->MessageId)) {
    //Log empty call here
}
```

Comment: I'd expect an array of zero messages to be returned if the query times out before any messages become available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really want to know the number of times you call the receive_message() on an empty AWS SQS queue you will have to use long polling. Because short polling has potential of returning empty list even when there are messages in the SQS queue. Reason being that in short polling AWS polls only a subset of servers and might return empty handed even if a message exist in the queue but residing in a server not polled during the cycle.

For more details about long and short polling [click here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/standard-queues.html#standard-queues-message-sample)

And you can check for returned list size to be zero to find if receive_message() was called on an empty AWS SQS